# How to reset the Text field by calling from another template in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, templates

In the bellow picture first one is security question which a drop down, and the second one is the text box which i want to be empty on changing the question
[image]

But the issue is that they both are different templates they both don't have any link
I used one controller to put regex between them. which is working fine. but the issue is i can not clear the text box when i change the security question .

Bellow is my drop down template for security question. the template is very big so just but the required part of the template code. **please refer the second part of data-ng-click**

```
<li data-ng-repeat="char in characteristic.getAvailableValues() | filter: {value: searchFilter}"
                        data-ng-class="{violatesCompatibilityRule: characteristic.doesValueViolateCompatibilityRule(char.id)}">
                        <a id="{{vm.productSpecIdPath}}---{{characteristic.characteristicSpecId}}---{{char.id}}---dropdownitem"
                        role="menuitem"
                        tabindex="-1"
                        href="javascript:void(0)"
                        data-ng-click="vm.selectCharacteristicValue(char.id); $root.securityQuestionRegex=characteristic.getSelectedValues()[0].regularExpression"
                        data-ng-bind="char.value">
                        </a>
```

Bellow is the Template for Input Box. **Please look at the ng-change**

```
<input ng-if="characteristic.getDisplayName() == 'Security Answer'"
          type="text"
          placeholder="{{'LABELS.USERDEFINEDCHARACTERISTICS.PLACEHOLDER.TEXT' | translate}}"
          id="{{vm.productSpecIdPath}}---{{characteristic.getUserDefinedCharacteristicId()}}---{{$index}}---input"
          name="{{characteristic.getUserDefinedCharacteristicId()}}-{{$index}}"
          data-ng-model="value.value"
          data-ng-change="value.value=$root.textboxRegexValidation(value.value);"
          data-ng-disabled="characteristic.isReadOnly() || vm.isReserved"             
          data-ng-class="{ isReadOnly: characteristic.isReadOnly(), 'reduced-input-width': characteristic.getTooltipId(), dirty: characteristic.isDirty() }"
          sigma-validation-pattern="{{characteristic.getRegularExpression()}}"/>
```

Bellow is my part of controller code

```
        $rootScope.textboxRegexValidation = function (obj: any) {


        if ($rootScope.securityQuestionRegex) {
            var regEx = new RegExp($rootScope.securityQuestionRegex);
            if (regEx.test(obj)) {
                return obj;
            } else {
                return obj.substring(0, obj.length - 1);
            }
        } else {
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please ignore the assigned value to $root.securityQuestionRegex in the security question template. you can suppose it as any regex string passing to it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo.. I got the solution
I put one extra flag in ng-click of my dropdown template "$root.emptyTextFlag"

```
<a id="{{vm.productSpecIdPath}}---{{characteristic.characteristicSpecId}}---{{char.id}}---dropdownitem"
                        role="menuitem"
                        tabindex="-1"
                        href="javascript:void(0)"
                        data-ng-click="vm.selectCharacteristicValue(char.id); $root.securityQuestionRegex=characteristic.getSelectedValues()[0].regularExpression; $root.emptyTextFlag = true"
                        data-ng-bind="char.value">
                        </a>
```

And in my text box field i used ng-value which evaluate my angular expression at run time "ng-value="value.value= $root.checkEmptyTextFlag() ?  '' : value.value"

```
 <input ng-if="characteristic.getDisplayName() == 'Security Answer'"
          type="text"
          placeholder="{{'LABELS.USERDEFINEDCHARACTERISTICS.PLACEHOLDER.TEXT' | translate}}"
          id="{{vm.productSpecIdPath}}---{{characteristic.getUserDefinedCharacteristicId()}}---{{$index}}---input"
          name="{{characteristic.getUserDefinedCharacteristicId()}}-{{$index}}"
          data-ng-model="value.value"
          data-ng-change="value.value= $root.textboxRegexValidation(value.value) "
          ng-value="value.value= $root.checkEmptyTextFlag() ?  '' : value.value"
          data-ng-blur= "$root.isMappingRuleTrigger(characteristic.getUserDefinedCharacteristicId()) ? vm.emitToggledEvent() : 'false'"
          data-ng-disabled="characteristic.isReadOnly() || vm.isReserved"             
          data-ng-class="{ isReadOnly: characteristic.isReadOnly(), 'reduced-input-width': characteristic.getTooltipId(), dirty: characteristic.isDirty() }"
          sigma-validation-pattern="{{characteristic.getRegularExpression()}}"/>
```

And finally in my controller i toggle the flag with the use of setTimeout in function checkEmptyTextFlag()

```
$rootScope.textboxRegexValidation = function (obj: any) {
        if ($rootScope.securityQuestionRegex) {
            var regEx = new RegExp($rootScope.securityQuestionRegex);
            if (regEx.test(obj)) {
                return obj;
            } else {
                return obj.substring(0, obj.length - 1);
            }
        } else {
            return obj;
        }
    }; 

    $rootScope.checkEmptyTextFlag = function (obj: any) {
        if($rootScope.emptyTextFlag == true){
            setTimeout(function () {
                $rootScope.emptyTextFlag= false;
              }, 100);    
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When ever i click on any option from drop down it change the flag of $root.emptyTextFlag = true and due to this in the text box it clear the text and after 1/10 second it again make it false which make me enable to type in the text box. Its working now.. m so happy :) :P